# Unity Hololens debugging in Visual Studio with IL2CPP?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, il2cpp

I am running Unity 2018.2 and when building my Hololens project with IL2CPP, in Visual Studio 2017 I can no longer see any output when Debug.Log is called from my project's C# scripts.

I believe my question is related to this other question [What is the best way to debug IL2CPP code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52843627/what-is-the-best-way-to-debug-il2cpp-code).

I have followed these instructions https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html (Visual Studio (Windows)), the recommended tool installation for Hololens (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/install-the-tools) and the Hololens instructions on how to build a project in Unity   (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/holograms-100).

Is there anything else that should be enabled to see the debug.log outputs when building with IL2CPP?

Comment: See Josh Peterson's response: "No, that is entirely possible.I forgot that the Hololens build generates two Visual Studio projects, one with the C# code and one with the generated C++ code. Before you build a Hololens player in the Unity editor, find any C# script in the project and double-click on it from the Unity editor "Project" tab. That should open the C# code in Visual Studio that you need."

Comment: When I build I actually only see one project in my build folder. Everything is cpp related and not c#, but I may be missing something. If I do this, "Before you build a Hololens player in the Unity editor, find any C# script in the project and double-click on it from the Unity editor "Project" tab. That should open the C# code in Visual Studio that you need", this opens the VS project and respective C# scripts, but not the VS solution that was built, which is what I use to deploy in the Hololens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also had this issue using Unity 2019.1. and Visual Studio 2019. So in case anybody has troubles with that, I managed to get my desired debugging behavior by attaching a managed Unity Debugger to the App running on the HoloLens as described in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-at/archive/blogs/appconsult/how-to-debug-unity-projects-with-il2cpp-backends-on-the-hololens) post. Then, I changed my `Debug.Log` statements to `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine`. Basically, what you have to do is

1. Build your Unity Project with `Development Build`, `Script Debugging` and `Wait for managed debugger` options.
2. Make sure the HoloLens is connected to your PC via WiFi.
3. Deploy the generated VS solution to your HoloLens. Once the App starts, you will be asked to attach a managed debugger.
4. Open a new VS instance via Unity and go to `Debug -> Attach Unity Debugger`.
5. Select your HoloLens in the Popup.

You can then use Breakpoints, see outputs of `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` etc.

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need a debugger attached to see the output of `Debug.Log` calls. All of that output will go to the [player log](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html).

You may also want to try [Debug.LogError](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.LogError.html), which will display the error message in an on-screen window in the player, when you have made a development player build.

Comment: Thanks Josh! What I usually do is to run my build in VS with Release>Start debugging and then I always got the Debug.Log messages in the output window. So you are saying that that is not possible anymore and I have to check the player log file?

Comment: I was unaware that Hololnes builds put the Debug.Log statements in the Visual Studio output window. If that stopped working with IL2CPP, that sounds like a bug then. Can you send us a bug report via the Unity editor?